# How can I test for phylogenetic signal in a discrete trait ( i.e. counts of parasites)

Tags: regression

I am running a PGLMM with a Poisson error distribution in R to evaluate the effect of sociality (binomial) in parasite loads. I want to test for phylogenetic signal in discrete data (e.g counts of parasites in bird species). However, I found several ways of testing for phylogenetic signal on continuous data (phytools::phylosig ..pagel's, K,  ) and in categorical (data ape::delta), but not much in how to test this in discrete (count data). Any ideas will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link (https://github.com/mrborges23/delta_statistic) it might be helpful.

It is from this paper: Borges, R., Machado, J. P., Gomes, C., Rocha, A. P., & Antunes, A. (2019). Measuring phylogenetic signal between categorical traits and phylogenies. Bioinformatics, 35(11), 1862-1869.